# Laravel collection incrementing inside map not possible with arrow function

Tags: php, laravel, increment

I'm trying to increment during the `map` method, however my variable doesn't seem to save the new value. My code:

```
$position = 0;

$statement = $medias->map(fn(string $media) => [
                'position' => ++$position
            ])->values();
```

My expected result would be:

```
#items: array:4 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "position" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "position" => 2
    ]
    2 => array:4 [
      "position" => 3
    ]
    3 => array:4 [
      "position" => 4
    ]
  ]
```

However it's actually

```
 #items: array:4 [
        0 => array:4 [
          "position" => 1
        ]
        1 => array:4 [
          "position" => 1
        ]
        2 => array:4 [
          "position" => 1
        ]
        3 => array:4 [
          "position" => 1
        ]
      ]
```

Is incrementing inside `map` not possible or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is your error message? I bet, it can be solved with altering the following line like this: `$statement = $medias->map(fn(string $media) use($position) => [`

Comment: There's actually no error at all, everything runs fine, but it's giving me wrong values :/ I tried using your suggestion but PHPStorm is giving me this error: The 'use' keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside

Comment: That's because I was stupid and didn't read carefully. Otherwise, I would have seen that you used arrow functions and these don't need to use `use()`. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you expect `$position` variable to be passed by reference, which is not the case.

> Arrow functions use by-value variable binding. This is roughly equivalent to performing a use($x) for every variable $x used inside the arrow function. A by-value binding means that it is not possible to modify any values from the outer scope. Anonymous functions can be used instead for by-ref bindings. [PHP Manual - Arrow Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)

A workaround for you could be like this:

```
// Either
$posObj = new \stdClass();
$posObj->position = 0;
// or
$posObj = (object)array('position' => 0);

$statement = $medias->map(fn(string $media) => [
                'position' => ++$posObj->position
            ])->values();
```